# Find modified files using diff in multiple directories

Tags: file, diff, directory

I was wondering if there is a tool or method to check which files have been modified in multiple directories. I have a copy of the files in the same directory structure that I am sure it was not touch and another that is the one I want to check against the first one. I know diff is out there for that, but I just don't want to check one file at the time.

Thank you.

Comment: diff works with directories - check the man page

Comment: how is this question out of topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff -ru <fist_dir> <second_dir>` should do it.

Comment: But will that check the files differences inside each directory?